# Proving that a compact set which has a limit point at each point in the set is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, compactness

Suppose $f:K \to (-\infty, \infty), K $ is compact, and $f$ has a finite limit at each point of $K$, but may not be continuous on $K$. Show that f is bounded. Then what if we don't know if $f$ is finite.

I'm really confused on this one. Can anyone give me some guidance?

Comment: I think this wants you to use the Bolzano-Wierstrass theorem, do you know that theorem?

Comment: Doesn't that only work if $f$ is finite?

Comment: So, do you know the Bolzano-Wierstrass theorem?  It is a theorem that has nothing to do with functions, only sequences of points in compact sets.  If you know it, it would be helpful to state it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ has a finite limit at each point of $K$, for each point $x_0\in K$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-L|<1$, i.e. $f$ is bounded in $(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$. Since it holds for any point $x_0\in K$, $K\subset\bigcup_{x_0\in K}(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$, i.e. an open cover of $K$. Since $K$ is compact, there is a finite subcover that $K\subset\bigcup_{1\leqslant i\leqslant N}(x_i-\delta, x_i+\delta)$. Then $|f|<M$ on $K$ if we set $M=\max{(M_1,\cdots, M_N)}$, where $|f|<M_i$ on $(x_i-\delta, x_i+\delta)$. So $f$ is bounded on $K$.

If $f$ doesn't have finite limit at each point of $K$, $f$ may not be bounded on $K$ for it may not be bounded on $(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$.

Comment: I will upvote after some editing.  The function $f$ is defined only  on $K$.  The condition $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<1$ does not follow from the assumption that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ exists.

Comment: Bit more:  If $\lim_{x\to x)} f(x)=L$ then $|f(x)-L|<1$ for $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$.  That gives $|f(x)|< |L|+1$, but doesn't give $|f(x_0)|<|L|+1$ but this is only one point to handle.  And the statement is not that $f$ is bounded on $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ but only for those points of $K$ that are in that interval. [Remember $f$ is defined on $K$ not necessarily on an interval containing $K$.]

Comment: A just a notational quibble:  the $\delta$ depends on the point--the same $\delta$ does not work at every point so your cover should look more like $$(x_i-\delta_i,x_i+\delta_i)$$ otherwise it is suggesting a cover of uniform size which might be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Please explain: "Then what if we don't know if $f$ is finite?"  But you described the function as mapping $K$ into $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Here is what you know:

> At every point $x\in K$ you know there is a $\delta(x)>0$ so that $f$
>   is bounded on both $(x-\delta(x),x)\cap K $ and $(x,x+\delta) \cap K$.
>   But $f(x)$ is finite so in fact $f$ is bounded on 
>   $(x-\delta(x),x+\delta(x))\cap K $.  That is the situation you are in
>   and you should be able to construct a proof.

When you are doing this kind of compactness problem you should try to be aware of just how similar they all are.  I would describe it this way: *if there is a local condition [state condition] that holds at every point of a compact set $K$, then that condition holds globally on $K$.*

You must have seen this many times: continuous locally at each point of a compact set implies uniform continuity.  Or, here locally bounded implies globally bounded.  Or locally constant on $[a,b]$ implies constant.  Locally increasing on $[a,b]$ implies increasing. Locally Lipschitz on $[a,b]$ implies globally Lipschitz. Etc.

Comment: By the way, the problem as posed is way too weak.  I would have posed   the condition $$\limsup_{y\in K, y\to x} f(y) < \infty$$ at each $x\in K$ and asked for the conclusion that $f$ is bounded above on $K$.